# Iframe align with parent <p>

Tags: html, css, iframe, alignment

My site is devided in 4 sections, every section has a h3 and a `<p>`. All content in the `<p>`
is centered with `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;` it also has a background-color and border. The `<p>` also grows automatic with its content.

In the one of the `<p>` is an iframe which is also centered, but i need it aligned to the left. The iframe is smaller than the width of the `<p>`.

float: left works, but the iframe gets closed out of the `<p>`. So my `<p>` is just on line and the iframe floats out of it.

Any idea why this happens?

http://jsfiddle.net/dennym/KBShz/

Comment: Can you show us an example on http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Why is the iframe centered? Do you also have `text-align:center` on the `<p>`?

Comment: see my edit, delete the #frame float to see what i mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding:

```
#another p { overflow: hidden; }
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KBShz/13/

Comment: That's a very unexpected behaviour, since that's not what that property is supposed to do... will that work for any floating div issue like this?

Comment: This works perfectly :/ the iframe is aligned to the left and all the text on the right side is still centered

Answer (score 0):

Here, I updated your fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/KBShz/14/

The reason that happens is because of how browsers treat floating elements.  They behave differently, and their container does not grow to fit them any longer.  Use `text-align: left` instead for that situation.

In other situations, you may need to place a `<div style="clear:both"></div>` at the end of your container div, to tell it to grow to fit its contents.